# Howto prevent "expansion" on standard notifications?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm creating a notification in my app:

```
Notification.Builder lBuilder = new Builder(...);
lBuilder.setGroup(...).setGroupSummary(true);

Notification notification = lBuilder.setTicker(tTicker)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_notification)
        .setContentTitle(tTitle)
        .setContentText(tText)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setShowWhen(false)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .build();
```

Currently it looks like this below:

[image]

[image]

I wish to eliminate the "expanding" feature. My goal is to have a notification as on the top image, without the possibility to expand it.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: I don't think that you have control over that, strictly speaking. You could try removing some of your content (title, text) and see if that happens to work for the specific device that you are testing. Just bear in mind that the notification shade frequently is customized by device manufacturers, and how they choose to render your notifications is up to them.